# Terminate a Flink job when using a Kafka Source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

When my producer has finished streaming all of its messages to Kafka, and after Flink has finished processing them, I want to be able to terminate the Flink job so it doesn't keep running, and also so I can know when Flink has finished processing all the data. I also cannot use batch processing as I need Flink to run in parallel to my Kafka stream.

Usually, Flink uses the `isEndOfStream` method in a `DeserializationSchema` class to see if it should end early (returning true in the method would automatically end the job). However, when using Kafka as a source with Flink, the new `KafkaSource` class has deprecated the use of the `isEndOfStream` method in deserializers and no longer checks it to see if the stream should end or not. Is there any other way to terminate a Flink job early?

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism provided by the `KafkaSource` for operating on bounded streams is to use `setBounded` or `setUnbounded` with the builder, as in

```java
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource
        .<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(...)
        .setGroupId(...)
        .setTopics(...)
        .setDeserializer(...) // or setValueOnlyDeserializer
        .setStartingOffsets(...)
        .setBounded(...) // or setUnbounded
        .build();
```

`setBounded` indicates that the source should be stopped once it has consumed all of the data up through the specified offsets.

`setUnbounded` can be used instead to indicate that while the source should not read any data past the specified offsets, it should remain running. This allows the source to participate in checkpointing if running in STREAMING mode.

If you know upfront how much you want to read, this works fine. I've used `setBounded` with a specific timestamp, e.g.,

```java
  .setBounded(
    OffsetsInitializer.timestamp(
      Instant.parse("2021-10-31T23:59:59.999Z").toEpochMilli()))
```

and also like this

```java
  .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
```

Comment: Since my producer is running in parallel to the Flink job via streaming mode, I will not have the latest offset or the timestamp of the last message at the beginning of the job. Instead, I will only have this information after some time when the producer has finished running. Is it possible to add a bound later instead of at the beginning of creating a job?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this.

Comment: when I use `.setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())` Flink is not committing offset to the kafka. how to commit offset in bounded kafka source?

Comment: Offsets are committed during checkpointing. This requires streaming mode, and leaving the job running long enough that a checkpoint completes after consuming all of the data.